# How do I make this block slide back and forth with each click - LibGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have this code already that makes the block move from the left to the right when the mouse is clicked once. What I want to achieve is for the block to move back to the left again when the mouse is clicked once more and then to the right again and so on and so forth with each respective click. I will include images below so you have an idea of what I am trying to achieve.

Code so far:

```
boolean hasBeenTapped = false;

public void update(float delta){

    velocity.x += speed*delta;

    if (Gdx.input.justTouched()){
        hasBeenTapped = true;
    }

    if (hasBeenTapped && getX() < 864){
        setX(getX() + velocity.x*delta);

    }

    if (getX()>864){
        setX(864);
    }


}
```

Images:

This is what it the game starts out like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5CDU.png

This is what it ends up like when I click the mouse once: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnZA1.png

I'd like to be able to click the mouse multiple times and make it slide between these two points.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your code. You have some parameter called `speed` but it looks like you're using it as an acceleration, since it's being added to velocity on each frame. An acceleration that is always in effect. So if you open your game and wait a few seconds before first tapping the screen, the block will move at a crazy fast speed.

Comment: I just realised that, that needs to be changed, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: I have got rid of the acceleration and now it just moves at a constant speed. I just did +90f instead of velocity.x*delta etc. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: You'll still want to multiply some number (your speed) by `delta` to get the distance moved in that frame. Using a straight number that doesn't involve `delta` will give inconsistent results if there is any variation in frame rate. And you can't guarantee frame rate will be the same on all devices or never slow down a bit while a phone is doing some background task or something.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Ah right, thanks a lot again! So now I have `setX(getX() + 800f*delta);` which should give consistent results and not speed up as more time passes in the game?

Comment: Yes, that's right. So 800 is your speed (pixels per second) which you multiply by your delta (seconds) to get distance moved that frame (in pixels). [Speed * Time = Distance]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not test the following code, but it should be working for you or at least it can give you an idea:

```
boolean control = false;
velocity.x += speed * delta;

if (Gdx.input.justTouched()){
    hasBeenTapped = true;
}

if (hasBeenTapped && getX() < 864 && control == false){
    setX(getX() + velocity.x*delta);            
}

if (getX()>864){
    setX(864);          
    control = true;         
    hasBeenTapped = false;
}

if (hasBeenTapped && getX() == 864 || getX() < 864 && control == true){
    setX(getX() - velocity.x * delta);
}

if (getX()< 0){
    setX(0);    
    control = false;
    hasBeenTapped = false;                      
}
```

Comment: I think the question was how can I make it move in the other direction, and I think the answer does that, that after the question is changed, becoming focused on speed and other factors, in the end my response may be of the most awkward possible becoming something entirely different, the code is based on the code of the question, it could take many forms, but almost eh followed the line that the asker did in your code, this does not say that I think it is wrong to add other code to improve the contrary I feel great, but that they will vote for the response focus on the original question

Answer (score 0):

**If speed is the current speed** of the block, you can simply invert it on each tap so then the block would move in the opposite direction:

```
if (Gdx.input.justTouched()){
   hasBeenTapped = true;
   speed = - speed;
}
```

If you want to invert the direction also when reaching the borders:

```
if (getX()<0 || getX()>864){
   speed = - speed;
}
```

Also you need the left bound check:

```
if (getX()<0) { 
   setX(0);
}
```

You should also consider the width of the block when checking the left or the right bound otherwise you would have that a part of the block is going after the bound.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify this as much as possible, you can use the clamp function to make sure your block is always within the range you want. I changed `hasBeenTapped` to `shouldMove` since I figure it's likely your test for whether it should move will become more sophisticated later.

```
boolean shouldMove = false;

public void update(float delta){

    if (Gdx.input.justTouched()){
        shouldMove = true;
        speed *= -1; //negate the speed to reverse directions
    }

    if (shouldMove)
        setX( Math.clamp(getX() + speed*delta, 0, 864) );
    }
}
```